# exist other way for select much element with the add() Jquery?

Tags: jquery, optimization

I have this code :

```js
$( "li" ) .add( "p" ) .add("pre") .add("small") .add("strong") .css( "background-color", "red" );


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

  <ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
</ul>
  <pre>hello</pre>
  
  <small>a small</small>
  <br>
  <strong>a strong</strong>
</body>
</html>
```

so I would like select all the element with a function only , how I can select all without use much code ?

I would like improve my  code

Comment: comma separate them, just like in css

Comment: ^ Or just use CSS in the first place

Comment: this way:  $( "li" ) .add( "p","pre","small").css( "background-color", "red" );

Comment: You don't need the add at all, and put them all in a single string with commas.  not multiple strings.   http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Comment: this way; $( "li" ) .add( "p, small , small").css( "background-color", "red" );

Comment: Sure, but like I said.  You don't need the add.  You can put them all in the `$()`

Comment: Please take some time to review the learn.jquery.com site to read up on some of the fundamentals with using the library.  It will greatly help you in using it.

Comment: `$("li, p, small, strong")`